# Add more conditions to Haversine Formula in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Please I need help with adding one more condition to the below database query. I'm using `Haversine Formula` to get the 15 closest locations to my user's location. I have succeeded in doing this, however I wish to narrow the condition to only display the closest locations if `serviceName` equals a `$serviceName` in my query.

I wish to add `WHERE serviceName="$serviceName";`.

My Query:

```
$sql = "
SELECT uid, inCallPriceOneTime, lat, lng, distance 
FROM
( 
    SELECT z.uid, z.inCallPriceOneTime, z.lat, z.lng, 
        p.radius, p.distance_unit * 
        DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint)) * 
        COS(RADIANS(z.lat)) * 
        COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint - z.lng)) 
        + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint)) * 
        SIN(RADIANS(z.lat)))) 
        AS distance 
    FROM selectedservice AS z 
    JOIN
    (  
        SELECT $lat AS latpoint, $lng AS longpoint, 50.0 AS radius, 
            111.045 AS distance_unit
    ) AS p 
    WHERE z.lat
    BETWEEN p.latpoint - (p.radius / p.distance_unit) 
    AND p.latpoint + (p.radius / p.distance_unit) 
    AND z.lng 
    BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * 
        COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint)))) 
    AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit *
        COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
) AS d 
WHERE distance <= radius 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 15";
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should at least take the time to format your current query so that it is readable.  Doing so would probably already get you 50% towards getting the answer you want.

Comment: I try my best @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Thanks for your attempts to help me out. After spending some time with the query I was able to squeeze in my condition and it's working fine now. I had to use id as integer rather that using serviceName which is a string.